# How to make a python function work without the required number of arguments?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem that requires to return a string of numbers with the round function. Here is my code:

```
def get_percentage(num, round_digits):
    if round_digits is None:
        return str(num * 100) + "%"
    else:
        return str(round(num * 100, round_digits)) + "%"
```

The problem occurs when I try to call get_percentage with just 1 argument. Is there any way to fix this?
Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the function with a default argument

```
def get_percentage(num, round_digits=None):
```

then you can call it with just the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to call the function without supplying the `round_digits` argument?

Try this:

```
def get_percentage(num, round_digits=None):
    if round_digits is None:
        return str(num * 100) + "%"
    else:
        return str(round(num * 100, round_digits)) + "%"
```

By adding `=None` after the argument `round_digits` you're identifying a default value.  And therefore, not required.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I was actually confused about assigning values in the definition itself.

Comment: Yeah, you can set default there. Just make sure they are at the end.  Otherwise it won't work.